# Ifconfig result on the server running PF_RING with zerocopy

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, packet-capture, packet-sniffer

I have an application which uses  PF_Ring zero copy as a part of its packet sniffing capability. When this application is running would it be possible to find out the amount of RX/TX traffic using ifconfig or is it correct to say that ifconfig does not show the correct RX/TX traffic since the OS does not have access to the incoming packets?